# How exactly did Auguste Bravais come up with the regression line?

Tags: mathematics, physics, calculus, discoveries, machine-learning

I am new to statistics and linear regression and I came across the face that auguste bravais discovered regression line but didn't realize it.

> Auguste Bravais (1811-1863), professor of astronomy and physics, is
> probably best known for his work in crystallography (Nelson, 1998).
> With respect to error theory, he is best known for a paper he wrote in
> 1846 titled "Analyse mathématique sur les probabilités des erreurs de
> situation d'un point" [translated: "Mathematical analysis on the
> probability of errors of a point"]. This work is renowned for being
> the very first mathematical exposition of the theory of correlation.
> Pearson (1896), later to recall these remarks, said that it was
> Bravais who first discussed the fundamental theorems of the
> correlational calculus. In his famous paper of 1846, Bravais,
> mathematically, not empirically, found the equation of the normal
> surface for the frequency of error. Using both analytic and geometric
> methods, Bravais also essentially found what would eventually be
> coined "regression line." He did so through investigating how the
> various elliptical areas of the frequency surface vary given various
> directly observed quantities. Through this, he found the line of
> regression, but, in essence, did not realize it, and thus could not
> "make the leap" (Walker, 1929) necessary to claim the discovery of
> correlation or regression

My question is how did he use "various elliptical areas of the frequency surface" to come across the regression line? I don't understand it at all. Please use diagrams if you can. Not too much complex maths too cause I am a newbie. Just explain simply how that works.

Comment: The work is available online https://books.google.com/books?id=y3s_AAAAcAAJ&dq=Sur%20Les%20Probabilit%C3%A9s%20des%20Erreurs%20de%20Situation%20d%27un%20Point&pg=PA1 On a quick look it seemed to be about the first principal component rather than what we now know as one of the two regression lines but I could very well be wrong about that.